# Matlab doesn't update all of the figures

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following setup

```
for iter = 1:N
    "calcualtion"
    if mod(iter, 50) == 0
        figure(1)
        plot(something)
        figure(2)
        plot(something)
        figure(3)
        plot(something)
    end
end
```

The problem is MATLAB displays figures 1 and 2, and completely omits figure 3, unless the code is stopped or has finished running.
Any ideas how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `drawnow;` after updating your last plot.